# Keep clicked ellipse highlighted until other ellipse is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouseevent, ellipse

right now I have a canvas with a bunch of ellipses on it made wherever the user clicks. I'm trying to make it so when he clicks on one, a black border is displayed around it UNTIL he clicks on another. Right now I just have it so when he clicks on one, the border appears and stays there.

Here's the function that handles the clicking down on the ellipse.

```
    private void ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        selectedNodeEllipse = (Ellipse)sender;
        SelectedNode = (Node)selectedNodeEllipse.Tag; //just displays some info about the node

        selectedNodeEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

    }
```

All the ellipses are in a list (of type Node).

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the stroke before? Why can't you just set the `Stroke` property back to the original value before you assign a new `selectedNodeEllipse` value?

Comment: Stroke wasn't set before so it was just default. But I tried what you said by doing "selectedNodeEllipse.Stroke = default();" and it keeps saying "Type expected" error.

Comment: Sure. You can't use the `default` keyword without providing a type. If you haven't set the `Stroke` explicitly, the default should be `null`. So just use that: `selectedNodeEllipse.Stroke = null;`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. Don't know how I didn't catch that. I did something similar to what Walt did below using your suggestions and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the prior ellipse and brush in a variable and retrieve the data when assigning the new stroke property.

**Code**

```
private Ellipse selectedNodeEllipse;
private Ellipse previousEllipse = null;
private Brush previousBrush;

private void ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

  e.Handled = true;
  if (previousEllipse != null)
  {
    previousEllipse.Stroke = previousBrush;
  }
  selectedNodeEllipse = (Ellipse)sender;
  previousEllipse = selectedNodeEllipse;
  previousBrush = previousEllipse.Stroke;
  SelectedNode = (Node)selectedNodeEllipse.Tag; //just displays some info about the node

  selectedNodeEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did something similar to what you did and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What's the point of `previousEllipse`? When is this ever not the same value as `selectedNodeEllipse`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho  selectedNodeEllipse is a reference to the ellipse selected by the user with the mouse.  I use the previousEllipse to track the ellipse selected the last time the user selected an ellipse.  Otherwise, how do you know which ellipse to apply the old brush?

Comment: I guess my comment was too subtle. The "previous brush" is (according to the OP) `null`, and the ellipse to which to apply that value is the ellipse that is the current selection just before the current selection is changed. Your answer works, but it's got almost twice as much code in it than is actually needed.